# CMake: when to use add_definitions instead of set_target_properties(target PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS definitions)

Tags: c++, cmake

In CMake documentation, we can read:

**[add_definitions](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:add_definitions)**

> Adds flags to the compiler command line for sources in the current directory and below.

**[COMPILE_DEFINITIONS property on directories](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#prop_dir:COMPILE_DEFINITIONS)**

> COMPILE_DEFINITIONS: Preprocessor definitions for compiling a directory's sources.

**[COMPILE_DEFINITIONS property on targets](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#prop_tgt:COMPILE_DEFINITIONS)**

> COMPILE_DEFINITIONS: Preprocessor definitions for compiling a target's sources.

**[COMPILE_DEFINITIONS property on source files](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#prop_sf:COMPILE_DEFINITIONS)**

> COMPILE_DEFINITIONS: Preprocessor definitions for compiling a source file.

`COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` and `add_definitions` functionality seems to overlap. `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` property seems more flexible.

So it seems that COMPILE_DEFINITIONS property does everything add_definitions does, and even more.

**So, in which cases *must* we call add_definitions because COMPILE_DEFINITIONS property cannot be used?**

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`add_definitions` has existed in CMake since the very first build of CMake came online more than a decade ago.

`COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` is simply the newer, more flexible and fine-grained way to do it.

They will always both be around: since 99%+ of the existing `CMakeLists.txt` files in the world use `add_definitions`, it simply would not be wise to remove it. The CMake devs work very hard to maintain backwards compatibility... sometimes to the detriment of clarity and simplicity. And sometimes doing essentially the same thing in multiple differing ways.

So: `add_definitions` is primarily useful to configure pre-existing CMakeLists files -- for those projects that have been around since before `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` was introduced. And, since those projects use it, any newer projects that are based on what people learn from reading those CMakeLists files are also quite likely to use `add_definitions`.

But if using `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` alone is sufficient for your needs, there's certainly nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Could you explain how it's possible to know this? Is this in the documentation somewhere? What does one have to read to understand the mysteries of CMake??

Answer (score 8):

If you want to add `compile definition for target`, you can use this function `target_compile_definitions` which is more convenient， like add multiple `compile definitions` once, like:

```
add_executable (trie_io_test demo12.cpp)
target_compile_definitions(trie_io_test PRIVATE UNIT_TESTING=1 IO_TEST=1)
```

You can see this question [how to set multiple compile definitions for target executable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30546677/6329006) for more information also from this https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_compile_definitions.html.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not say that something **must** be used.

It is just matter of your habit.

Some recommendations:

- Use **add_definitions** when you want add to compiler command line
  for sources in the current directory and below. It is just shorter to
  type.
- Use **COMPILE_DEFINITIONS** for fine tuning of target or specific
  sources.

Comment: Thanks. My question was more to understand in which cases add_definitions is useful. Because it seems that COMPILE_DEFINITIONS property does the same and even more.

Comment: I gave you one reason - want to simplify - use add_definition. Want full control - use set_properties with COMPILE_DEFINITION.