# CMake - how to set multiple compile definitions for target executable?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to set multiple compile definitions for one of the executables I'm trying to compile in CMake (in order to activate macros used for debugging). Here's what I tried:

```
add_executable (trie_io_test trie_io_test.c trie.c word_list.c)
    set_target_properties(
            trie_io_test
            PROPERTIES
            COMPILE_DEFINITIONS UNIT_TESTING=1)
    set_target_properties(
            trie_io_test
            PROPERTIES
            COMPILE_DEFINITIONS IO_TEST=1)
```

Unfortunately this causes only the IO_TEST to be defined.

I also tried the following:

```
add_executable (trie_io_test trie_io_test.c trie.c word_list.c)
    set_target_properties(
            trie_io_test
            PROPERTIES
            COMPILE_DEFINITIONS UNIT_TESTING=1 IO_TEST=1)
```

But this, on the other hand, causes CMake error.

How to set both of these definitions for the executable I'm trying to build?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You want [`target_compile_definitions`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/target_compile_definitions.html) instead of `set_target_properties`:

```
target_compile_definitions(trie_io_test PRIVATE UNIT_TESTING=1 IO_TEST=1)
```

Comment: I linked to the docs in my answer, but it's really only useful for libraries rather than exes.  Libs can define their compile flags as `PRIVATE`, `PUBLIC` or `INTERFACE`.  `PRIVATE` basically means the flags are only applied to this library.  `PUBLIC` and `INTERFACE` flags are also applied to any target which links to it (i.e. its dependees); the difference between these two being that `INTERFACE` flags aren't applied to the library itself - only its dependees.

Comment: Thanks, for the reference, this is an answer to my question "What does PRIVATE mean in this case?" which I deleted, because I saw that there was a link to documentation after asking the question.

Comment: PRIVATE adds the property just to this target.

INTERFACE adds the property to targets that link to this target.

PUBLIC acts as both PRIVATE and INTERFACE because it adds the property to both this target and to targets that link to this target.

Comment: I'm missing the ability to set `optimized` and `debug` on them. Can use generator expressions, but I'm not sure if there is any that work with build configurations?

Comment: target_compile_definitions is available only to cmake > 3.0

Comment: This _appends_ the compile definitions, right? That is, we can use this command repeatedly with more definitions later on, right?

Comment: @einpoklum Yes, you can call it multiple times.

Answer (score 4):

I find this can work for you:

```
add_executable (trie_io_test trie_io_test.c trie.c word_list.c)
set_target_properties(
    trie_io_test
    PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS UNIT_TESTING=1
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS IO_TEST=1
   )
```

Just by adding another `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` :P

Comment: It didn't work for me when using with `set_source_files_properties()`. The second overwrites the first.

Comment: Does not work. One overwrites the other.

Answer (score 0):

This does work:

```
add_executable (trie_io_test trie_io_test.c trie.c word_list.c)
set_target_properties(
    trie_io_test
    PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "UNIT_TESTING=1;IO_TEST=1"
   )
```

No clue why this makes a difference. It was my understanding that in cmake, white space separated lists are equivalent to semicolon separated strings.

Comment: Isn’t this effectively just validating the previous, very similar answer? If not, can you highlight the difference? I see that the code is slightly different, but it’s unclear as a reader if that difference is critical here. Can you [edit] your answer to provide clarification?