# CMake add_definitions not scoped to current directory

Tags: c++, cmake

The [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_definitions.html) for `add_definitions` states that:

> Adds definitions to the compiler command line for sources in the current directory and below

But when I use it - doesn't matter where I put it - the definition gets added to every target across the entire project and prompts a full rebuild.  In the CMakeLists.txt for the target of interest I'm adding:

```
if (MY_OPTION)
  add_definitions(-DMY_DEFINITION)
endif()
```

And `-DMY_DEFINITION` shows up in the ninja.build file for every target across the entire project.  I've tried moving this block of code up and down in the folder hierarchy to no avail. I'm still on CMake 2.8.12 if that makes a difference, but the documentation there is the same.  Am I misusing this in some way, or is this the intended behavior?

Edit: Some details about the project structure in response to question from @Tsyvarev:

```
3rdParty/
   Dep1/
     CMakeLists.txt
   ...
CustomDep1/
  CMakeLists.txt
MyProject/
  Project.cmake
  CMakeLists.txt
  MyTarget1/
    CMakeLists.txt
```

The option is specified in Project.cmake.  Definition is only required by MyTarget1. I've tried to put `add_dependencies` in MyProject/CMakeLists.txt, and in MyTarget1/CMakeLists.txt.  It propagates to everything in 3rdParty, CustomDep1, etc.

Comment: Where you have this file, and where (in which file) you define target, which is affected by `add_definitions`, but shouldn't?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I updated the post to include more details in the hope of answering your question.

Comment: And you have top-level `CMakeLists.txt`, which does something like `add_subdirectory(MyProject)`, `add_subdirectory(3dParty)` (particular order has no meaning), don't you? Where `Project.cmake` is included? Does `MyProject` interract with `Dep1` somehow (e.g. links with the target, defined there)?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes to all - top level CMakeLists.txt, and `MyProject` either has a direct or transitory depence on `CustomDep1`, `Dep1`, etc.  MyProject/CMakeLists.txt furthermore has `add_subdirectory(MyTarget1)`.

Comment: BTW, this is a case, when [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be invaluable. Instead of providing several lines of code from several files, you are trying to describe complex dependencies between all of them.

Comment: You must clear the build cache files so you can get the updated files intermediate files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223779/cmake-when-to-use-add-definitions-instead-of-set-target-propertiestarget-prope) and use `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` for fine tuning of target or specific sources.

Also `add_definitions` works in current directory and below and current directory is a directory where lying CMakeLists.txt which include Project.cmake.

Comment: Thanks - I saw references to `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` but that SO answer helped to clarify its use. While the question remains about `add_dependencies` scope in my project, using `target_compile_definitions(MyTarget1 PRIVATE -DMY_DEFINITION)` did exactly what I wanted and better conveys the intent.

Comment: Okay, I finally understand what you mean by "current directory and below".  They are not talking about physical directories, but about the hierarchy implied by `add_subdirectory`.  Our make code is in effect a DAG, not a tree, so this blows up massively with `add_definitions`.